# Show that coefficient of homogeneous polynomial are determined by their degree and the difference of their index.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

I am given the homogeneous polynomial of degree $l$:
\begin{align}
u(x,y,z)=\sum_{a,b}c_{ab}(x+iy)^a(x-iy)^bz^{l-a-b}
\end{align}
Where $0 \leq a,b \leq l$.

I have to show that given $l$ and $m=a-b$, $c_{ab}$ is determined up to one multiplicative constant, by $l$ and $m=a-b$, when the laplacian of $u(x,y,z)$ is $0$.

Im having difficulty taking the laplacian of $u$ (which is also an exercise), but i've reached:

\begin{align}
\Delta u=\sum_{a,b} c_{ab}4ab(x+iy)^{a-1}(x-iy)^{b-1}z^{l-a-b}+c_{ab}(l-a-b)(l-a-b-1)(x+iy)^a(x-iy)^bz^{l-a-b-2}
\end{align}

I've reached the following about $b$ using that $a=m+b$: 
\begin{align}
0 \leq b \leq l-m \quad \text{for} \ m \geq 0\\
-m \leq b \leq l \quad \text{for} \ m \leq 0
\end{align}

Simply rewriting $\Delta u$ has yielded nothing. I think it has something to do with Legendre Functions, but i'm not sure how.